# UINavigationController popToViewController not popping

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Been working with `UIKit` for years now. It's amazing how issues like this seem to pop-up out of the blue.

I have a simple navigation setup:

- `UINavigationController`

  - `HomeViewController` [push]
  - `DetailViewController` [push]
  - `ModalViewController` [modal]

A root navigation controller with 2 children pushed onto the stack. Then a modal presented from the root nav controller.

For some reason, the following snippet of code isn't working as expected:

```swift
extension UINavigationController {

  func popToViewController(_ vc: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: @escaping ([UIViewController]?)->()) {

    let popped = popToViewController(viewController, animated: animated)

    if let coordinator = self.transitionCoordinator {
      coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { _ in
        completion(popped)
      }
    }
    else {
      completion(popped)
    }

  }

}
```

using the extension:

```swift
navigationController.popToViewController(
  homeViewController, 
  animated: true
)
```

No errors, warnings or crashes occur. UI is still fully responsive. **But** the `DetailViewController` in the stack is never popped. Inspecting the extension's `popped` variable, results in an empty array - which makes sense as the `DetailViewController` is clearly not removed from the stack.

What could prevent a navigation controller from popping a valid vc off of it's stack?

**Things I've checked:**

- `homeViewController` **is in the stack already**, and I'm asking it to pop to the same instance. i.e. `navigationController.viewControllers.contains(homeViewController) == true`
- I'm on the main thread. i.e. `Thread.isMainThread == true`
- `navigationController.viewControllers` returns the same array before & after calling `popToViewController(_vc:animated:)`
- Manually figuring out what vc's need to be popped, and calling `setViewControllers(_ vcs:animated:)` with the vcs I want to keep (in this case, just the `HomeViewController` instance). This still has the same issue.

I want to say this has something to do with popping view controllers off the stack from behind a modal presentation. But, as far as I know this is an okay thing to do. Plus, I've done it before and have had no issues in the past.

Comment: From which controller are you calling your custom `popToViewController`? It's not going to work from the presented modal because that's a different navigation controller.

Comment: @rmaddy Not being called from the modal. Definitely being called on the right `UINavigationController`. 

Comment: I would assume you need to dismiss the modal vc first.

Comment: hmmm... wait... you're presenting the modal VC from the Navigation Controller? Can you put together a [mcve]?

Comment: @DonMag I created a small example project, and it works as expected. Can confirm you do not need to dismiss the modal first. . I'm wondering if this is related to iOS 13's `modalPresentationStyle` changes.